# nullpointerexception error I know which line has error but how can I fix?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have looked nullpointerexception error but I can not find a solution for my codes I have googled it but there is not solution. you can see my codes below

```
public class oyuncuAdlariActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button kaleciKayit;
Button oyuncuKayit;
EditText isimGiris;
String isimGirisString;
int kaleciSayisi = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_oyuncu_adlari);
    kaleciKayit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kaleciButton);
    oyuncuKayit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oyuncuButton);
    isimGiris = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.isimGir);
    kaleciKayit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            kaleciSayisi++;
            isimGirisString = isimGiris.getText().toString();
            if (isimGirisString.isEmpty()){
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.isimBos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();
            }
            else if (kaleciSayisi >2)
                kaleciKayit.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
}
```

}
when I checked logcat it says line 24 has "nullpointexception" problem
line 24 is

```
kaleciKayit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

what is wrong with this? and I checked layouts they are true
here is activity_oyuncu_adlari.xml file

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/oyuncuButton"
        android:layout_width="227dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:text="@string/oyuncu_olarak_kaydet"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.434" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/isimleri_buraya_girin"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.133" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/isimGir"
        android:layout_width="227dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.188" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/kaleciButton"
        android:layout_width="227dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:text="@string/kaleci"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.313" />
```

Comment: What does this `kaleciKayit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kaleciButton);` return? I'm betting that it returns null since you may have not defined kaleciButton correctly in the XML file.

Comment: I defined it in xml I checked 20 times

Comment: Please *show* your xml resource file.

Comment: added you can check it out

Comment: so? can you find anything?

Comment: that looks OK to this untrained eye.  Have you tested -- what is null on the line throwing the exception? Have you gone through all the answers in the duplicate? Remember, only *you* have the complete code, and so only *you* can fully debug this thing

Comment: I wrote that line 24 has npe problem
`kaleciKayit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`
this line

Comment: No, ***what variable*** is null?

Comment: `kaleciKayit` is null

Comment: OK, that's a start. Now you need to debug the problem as per the answers in the duplicate -- go through each answer and see if it applies. I'm afraid that these NPE's can only be debugged by the person with the code. All we can do is direct you to resources that can help you in the task. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for help but why did you close my question? maybe someone else can help me?

Comment: Because *no  one can help you*. You must debug this yourself as per the duplicate

Comment: of course sir as you wish

Comment: Only you have compilable code. Only you can debug

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.easoft.aldimverdim.oyuncuAdlariActivity.onCreate(oyuncuAdlariActivity.java:27)`
this is what I got in logcat and line 27 is
`kaleciKayit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`
I am researching on google but nothing can help

Comment: FIXED! I just changed v23 XML

Comment: Yay!!! (you did what?)

Comment: I just copied original xml to v23 xml
it makes difference? because I dont know why app has v23 xml